# Java: Master Gain not supported exception

Tags: java, linux, audio, volume

In linux this code doesn't work: **I added two lines**

```
// Added two lines.
DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info( SourceDataLine.class, audioFormat );
SourceDataLine dataLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine( info );
// Adjust the volume on the output line.
if( dataLine.isControlSupported( FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN)) {
    // If inside this if, the Master_Gain must be supported. Yes?
    FloatControl volume = (FloatControl) dataLine.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
    // This line throws an exception. "Master_Gain not supported"
    volume.setValue( 100.0F );
}
```

Is this normal? What do I have to do to solve this?
**In windows does it work.**

Thanks, Martijn.

Comment: This seems to be a problem with the implementation of the 'dataLine' you are using. What is the type of the dataline? 
I would expect that getControl() only throws this exception when isControlSupported returns false...

Comment: It is possible that your dataLine is not the same type of dataline in windows and linux. You could investigate the type of the dataLine (which is a subtype of SourceDataLine) in both Linux and Windows by debugging this code.

Comment: Yes, it are the same types of lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you try to `open()` the line before trying to use controls on it. Something like this:

```
// Added two lines.
DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info( SourceDataLine.class, audioFormat );
SourceDataLine dataLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine( info );
dataLine.open();
// Adjust the volume on the output line.
if( dataLine.isControlSupported( FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN)) {
    // If inside this if, the Master_Gain must be supported. Yes?
    FloatControl volume = (FloatControl) dataLine.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
    // This line throws an exception. "Master_Gain not supported"
    volume.setValue( 100.0F );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it differs depending on the JRE version.

I'm having a similar problem and when I check dataLine.getControls(), I get a "MASTER_GAIN" Control on Oracle JDK 1.7 and a "Volume" Control on OpenJDK 1.6. And what makes it worse ... the "Volume" has a linear value from 0...65536 while the MASTER_GAIN seems to have a decibel setting.

So much for code once, run everywhere :-(